# PHP Checking if specify entered Email & Id are matching to the ones in the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have recently switched from Mysql_* to PDO, heard it's the new, better more secure way of connecting and working with MySQL databases.

I have learned many basics of it like queries, prepare, etc.

**What do I want to do**

I currently have two text fields, named 'Email' and 'ID'.
When user registers, he enters his email, after he registers he receives his own ID, something unique.
I want him to be able to check the status of his account, without any passwords.

Simply by entering his email, and id and clicking 'submit'.
After clicking submit, the system should check if there's a column with the same email & ID.
If there is a column with these same exact email & IDs, then I can create a while loop to grab information from his account's column like creation date, and others..

**My Question**

*How would I do this?*

There's what I've done so far:

```
if (isset($email) && isset($id) && isset($submit)) {

    $fetch = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1");
    $fetch->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $fetch->execute();

    $validate = $fetch->fetchColumn();
    if ($validate == 0) {
        echo 'failed';
    } else {
        echo 'not failed';
    }

    while($row = $fetch->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
    //We can fetch here...
    }

}
```

My friend suggested me to use fetchColumn() which is replacing mysql_num_columns function, but It doesn't seem to work.

I enter a right email address, and it is still echoing 'Failed' instead of 'Not failed'.

### Why doesn't this method work? Have I done this wrong?.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the first field in your table?

Comment: email address is the first one.

Comment: Hello ! Try to var_dump the $validate variable and tell us the result :)

Comment: @JonyKale BTW, there isn't a function named 'mysql_num_columns'  in php :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to fetch *columns*, but *rows*.  You also don't actually check the ID either, but you can just add an `AND` condition to your query if necessary.

```
$fetch->execute();
if ($fetch->rowCount()) {
    echo "Row was returned; match found";
}
else {
    echo "No match found";
    exit;
}
$row = $fetch->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

There will probably only be one row for you to fetch as well, but in case there aren't you can use the `while` loop as you did above.

Comment: This works like a charm! Isn't a better way to do this is, only looking if the email matches, and then using a while loop to fetch the 'id' in the email's column, and then doing like if ($id == $row['id']) { echo 'true'; } else { echo 'false'; } ?

Comment: @JonyKale I'm not sure .. can there be more than one row with the same `email`?

Comment: Nope but I have to check that ID is correct, so that account can't get 'hacked'. This is basically a recovery system, you can check your recovery's status by entering your email and the ID given when you created the recovery.

Comment: @JonyKale just update the query to check for `AND id = :id` and bind that value as well.

Answer (score 0):

`$validate` is a string containing the email address. When doing `if ($validate == 0)` you're typecasting `$validate` to an integer, and any non-numeric string becomes `(int) 0`, and so the comparison is always true.

Change to `if ($validate === FALSE)`.

Comment: Thanks for this, never knew it checks by true/fasle. by the way is there any massive difference between ' == ' and ' === ' ?

Comment: `0 == FALSE` will return `TRUE`; `0 === FALSE` will return `FALSE`. When using three equal signs the value's `type` is taken into account as well, which is what you need in this case.